# Freshman-level presentation of quantum mechanics using decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, specific-reference, decoherence

Probably within the last year, I came across a recent textbook or textbook-style presentation of quantum mechanics, at the freshman level, that introduced the subject from scratch using decoherence. I think the text was online and not paywalled. Now I can't remember where I found it, and I can't seem to find it by googling. Can anyone point me to it?

Comment: *::blinks::* Really? I'd like to see that, too.

Comment: It's possible that I had in mind this book by Binney, http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/QBhome.htm , although it's more of an upper-division text.

Answer (score 1):

I finally remembered what book I'd had in mind. It's Griffiths, **Consistent Quantum Theory**, which is available in print and for free [online](http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/CQT/index.html). Although it does have a chapter on decoherence at the end of the book, my memory was wrong. It focuses on the consistent histories approach, not decoherence.